# MIPS parser using C# Pidgin, failing to parse a sequence of things

Tags: c#, parsing, parser-combinators

I am trying to write a simple parser combinator to parse MIPS code using the Pidgin library but my `SeparatedAndOptionallyTerminated` parser always finds a single thing to the parser and no error is thrown. I am not sure what is going on.

I appreciate any help or hint.

```
var skipCommaP = Char(',').IgnoreResult();

var registerP = Char('$')
    .Then(Enums.GetValues<Register>().Select(x => x.Name())
        .Select(x => String(new string(x.Skip(1).ToArray())))
        .Aggregate((a, b) => a.Or(b))
        .Map(v => $"${v}".ToRegister()));

var loadImmediateP = Map(
    (a, b, c) => (Instruction) new LoadImmediate(b, c),
    String(LoadImmediate.Name).Between(SkipWhitespaces),
    registerP.Before(skipCommaP.Optional()).Between(SkipWhitespaces),
    Num.Between(SkipWhitespaces)
);

var moveP = Map(
    (a, b, c) => (Instruction) new Move(b, c),
    String(Move.Name).Between(SkipWhitespaces),
    registerP.Before(skipCommaP.Optional()).Between(SkipWhitespaces),
    registerP.Between(SkipWhitespaces)
);

var instructionsP = loadImmediateP.Or(moveP);

ProgramP = instructionsP.SeparatedAndOptionallyTerminated(EndOfLine);
```

Then using it:

```
const string code = "move $t0, $t0 \n" + 
                    "li $t0 555";

var result = new MipsParser().ProgramP.Parse(code);

// result.Value has single thing in it always.
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[My repo](https://github.com/amir734jj/mips-simulator/tree/96034f999b49fc57d273cfd0f442f318c01a2b1c)

Answer (score 1):

SkipWhitespaces parser from Pidgin consumes line breaks. It's somewhat sofisticated under the hood to optimize consuming large chunks of white spaces a little bit faster, but what it boils down to is - it consumes everything that is considered a whitespace by `char.IsWhiteSpace` [Link to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=net-7.0)

So, when moveP MapParser executes, it consumes line break, and there is nothing left for `SeparatedAndOptionallyTerminated` parser to separate your lines by.

Parser reads one line (including line break), separated parser notes that whatever is left in the input certainly doesn't look like EndOfLine, and simply exits. Not consuming the entire input is not in itself an exceptional situation, so Separated parser just returns the first line.

Now I'm not sure what's the best way to remediate this issue. You can always define your own version of SkipWhitespaces parser that does not consume line breaks, or you can pre-replace line breaks in incoming code with hardcoded non-whitespace value like `"__THIS_WAS_END_OF_LINE_ONCE_UPON_A_TIME__"` and then call `SeparatedAndOptionallyTerminated` on that to break up your lines.